# Check if times overlap in calendar

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a calendar/agenda program (in Python3) that takes in appointments as defined by a user and stores them, however, I am having some difficulty with my overlap function. Ideally I don't want users to be able to schedule two appointments at the same time or so they crossover, but I can't make my overlap function work properly. It currently lets you schedule multiple appointments for the same/overlapping times and I'm not quite sure how to fix it. I have included my code for the overlap function below, if anything else is needed just let me know!

```
def overlap(self, other):
  if other.start_time < self.start_time < other.end_time:
     return False
  elif other.start_time < self.end_time < other.end_time:
     return False
  return True
```

Comment: If `self.start_time` is before `other.start_time`, and `self.end_time` is after `other.end_time`, your function won't detect that

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thank you! I’ve been looking at all my code for so long I wasn’t even seeing that, it’s been a long day..!

Answer (score 1):

Patrick is correct, you also need to check if other starts or ends between self.

```
def overlap(self, other):
  if other.start_time < self.start_time < other.end_time:
     return False
  elif other.start_time < self.end_time < other.end_time:
     return False
  elif self.start_time < other.start_time < self.end_time:
     return False
  elif self.start_time < other.end_time < self.end_time:
     return False
  return True
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I’ll give this a go and hopefully it’ll work for me now! Been looking at my code for so long I wasn’t even seeing it anymore, thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome! If this example works please make sure to accept it as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can also express non overlapping durations by saying that the later one only begins once the earlier one ends:

```
def overlap(self, other):
    return self.end_time <= other.start_time or other.end_time <= self.start_time
```